# Google App-Script DocsListDialog.showDocsPicker() does not execute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have the following code in my script (which is non-contained and started from scratch), but for some reason, the showDocsPicker() function does nothing.  No dialog comes up, the event handler is never called, and there's no error in the logs or on screen.  When I debug, the picker object *seems* valid.

```
function mailMerge() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Spreadsheet-Doc Merge");

  var docPicker = app.createDocsListDialog().setDialogTitle("Pick Document").setInitialView(UiApp.FileType.DOCUMENTS);
  docPicker.addSelectionHandler(app.createServerHandler("docHandler"));
  Logger.log("Pick Doc");
  docPicker.showDocsPicker();

  var ssPicker = app.createDocsListDialog().setDialogTitle("Pick Spreadsheet").setInitialView(UiApp.FileType.SPREADSHEETS);
  ssPicker.addSelectionHandler(app.createServerHandler("ssHandler"));
  Logger.log("Pick ss");
  ssPicker.showDocsPicker();

  doMerge();

  return app;
}

function docHandler(e) {
  Logger.log("docHandler Event");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  selectedDocId = e.parameter.items[0].id;
  UserProperties.setProperty("docId", e.parameter.items[0].id);
  Logger.log("Selected doc: " + e.parameter.items[0].id);

  return app;
}

function ssHandler(e) {
  Logger.log("ssHandler Event");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  UserProperties.setProperty("spreadsheetId", e.parameter.items[0].id);
  selectedSpreadsheetId = e.parameter.items[0].id;
  Logger.log("Selected spreadsheet: " + e.parameter.items[0].id);

  return app;
}

function doMerge() {
  var docId = UserProperties.getProperty("docId");
  Logger.log("UserProperties.getProperty docId: " + UserProperties.getProperty("docId"));
  var spreadsheetId = UserProperties.getProperty("spreadsheetId");
  Logger.log("UserProperties.getProperty spreadsheetId: " + UserProperties.getProperty("spreadsheetId"));

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var text = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().editAsText();

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var fieldNames = values[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log("Processing row " + i + ": " + row);

    for (var f = 0; f < fieldNames.length; f++) {

      text.replaceText("\\[" + fieldNames[f] + " " + i + "\\]", row[f]);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: I added the rest of the code. I had the return app;  Maybe my expectation is wrong.... I'm expecting this code to popup a document selector and that the handler will then be called when the selection is made.  Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my code was that it did not anticipate the asyncronous threads that the dialogues are launched in.  Once those dialogues are "shown" the program continues to the doMerge() method before the files selections are made (which causes an invalid argument error).

The solution is to chain the program flow through the event handlers.  So the end of the first handler creates the second dialogue, and the end of the second handler calls the doMerge() method.

The one peculiarity I found was that it does not run in the Editor.  The only way to run the script is to deploy it as a webapp.  I suspect this is because the UI Service is not an available class, or that the Editor does not support UI interaction.

Comment: I'm honestly interested in why you think this is wrong.  This isn't personal.  We're both here to learn.

Comment: I see what you mean, this post is getting unreadable... I'll delete my answer, useless to anybody. – I didn't notice you were setting the properties in the handler, I thought that came from anothrer function. That said, it can be easily checked in the execution transcript, you would have seen that there was an error opening the doc & spreadsheet, nothing to do with UiApp.

Comment: Actually, without your advice to deploy to web app, I would never have tried that since I was building a stand alone script. 

What's interesting is that it doesn't work in the Editor, and in the execution script, it just says "DocsListDialog.showDocsPicker() [0 seconds]".  Which, I think, means the UiApp isn't available in the Editor.